# Yii2 как сделать связь многие ко многим с условием?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, many-to-many

Не совсем понимаю один момент, например, есть три связанные таблицы: статья, теги и связующая таблица id_tag и id_post.
Сделать просто вывод по всем трём таблицам, не составило труда, но если я вписываю условие, то бд выдает ошибку

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'tags_post.tag_id' in 'where clause' The SQL being executed was:
>   SELECT * FROM `blog` WHERE `tags_post`.`tag_id`='3'

Код в контроллере:

```
public function actionCategory($id){
    $blog = Blog::find()
        ->where(['tags_post.tag_id' => $id])
        ->with('tags')
        ->all();
    return $this->render('blog', ['blog' => $blog]);
}
```

Без условия WHERE все работает, но как тогда это можно реализовать?
Это кстати, метод из модели ActiveRecord

```
public function getTags(){
        return $this->hasMany(Tags::classname(), ['tag_id' => 'tag_id'])
            ->viaTable('tags_post', ['post_id' => 'id']);   
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас же запрос строится без соединения со связанной таблицей. Попробуйте так:

```
public function actionCategory($id){
    $blog = Blog::find()
        ->joinWith('tags')
        ->where(['tags_post.tag_id' => $id])        
        ->all();
    return $this->render('blog', ['blog' => $blog]);
}
```

Comment: Блин, точно!) Спасибо большое)